# JRockit : -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jrockit

I would like to know all the list of JRockit memory parameters.

Does JRocket has something like "-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures".Any Idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JRockit command line reference page lists all the various options possible,

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/toc.htm

`-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures` seems to be asbsent.

Answer (score 1):

The -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures is on the merged version of Hotspot and JRockit now called Java Mission Control which ships with Java7u40 and later which allows for the use of the Java Flight Recorder in JMC 5.2 - hope that helps